# Preview codes of IFrame in JQuery dialog box

Tags: iframe, text, editor

OK guys, I am making a basic text editor. I have an Iframe where the user will write their HTML codes. I am using JavaScript execommand for some WYSIWYG functions like Bold, Italic etc.. Everything is working fine like a BOSS.

I want to preview their codes what have written in a JQuery dialog box or open in a new window. I want to know if it is possible for this? We can do this with a textarea, but I am using IFrame here.

**Here is my code Iframe:**

```
<iframe name="code" id="code"></iframe>
```

**Here is my DIV to preview the written code in the dialog box of JQuery UI:**

```
<div id="preview"></div>
```

**Here is my JavaScript code to preview in the dialog box of JQuery UI:**

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        $( "#preview" ).dialog();
    });
    </script>
```

Of course, I just put the dialog box basic code, but how to preview the written codes from the IFrame to the dialog box? For example, if the user has written "Hello" in the Iframe in bold using CSS or HTML, the word "Hello" should be in bold in the dialog box when previewing. Also, can I know how to do the preview by opening in a new window as well?

Thank